# Colour code images on Windows?

Tags: gratis, windows-7

I hope this question makes sense but I am looking for some type of explorer integrated program or utility that allows me to organise or tag photos with some type of special coloured badge or something.

The reason: I have a special folder with photos named "FB Posts". In this folder I usually place photos that I find really cool and so usually put them in there so when I feel like it or if I want to, I post them on facebook however sometimes I forget which photos I have already posted up because I have so many photos or 102 photos and counting to be exact.

I have tried sorting them by day of upload when uploading some to facebook. The only problem with this is I don't always upload them or post a photo in order. E.g. I don't post my photos from order of 1 to 10 but rather if this makes sense, from coolest to most interesting (so randomly).

Also I don't post them all on one day, but over the course of the week. Is there a program or some program that integrates in explorer that allows me to for example highlight a filename in a colour like Red? Ideally I would like a program that is free, runs on Windows 7 and runs without administrative rights.

Any suggestions/ideas?